# Make PWA with React with serviceWorker

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a problem with React.

When you doing a create-react-app, you have a file : sercice-worker.js
I used a template and this file doesn't exist.
I'm trying differents solutions to install service-worker, serviceWorker packages, in mobile, nothing happened. I can't download my application in mobile.

How can I installs service-worker for having the PWA ?

Thx

Comment: The serviceWorker running only in "production", are you in production?

Comment: Yes I have 3 environnements. When I build, I'm in production

Answer (score 0):

Create a JavaScript file in the public folder of your React project. This file will be your custom service worker. Then register this service worker by using a script placed in the body of your index.html

```
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
       window.addEventListener('load', function() {
       navigator.serviceWorker.register('./your-custom-service-worker.js');
       });
    }
```